# How to print the reverse of NSString in objective c without using componentsSeparatedByString method?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I want to make a method which gives reverse of string.suppose I pass a NSString "Welcome to Objective C" in method and that method return a reverse of string like "C Objective to Welcome" not "C evitcejbO ot emocleW" without the use of  componentsSeparatedByString method.
Is it possible to do with Objective c..?
Please help.

Comment: @AdamM That's **specifically what OP does not want to do.**

Comment: @OP: "without the use of componentsSeparatedByString method" - *why?*

Comment: SOMEONE ASKED ME THIS QUESTION..print a reverse of string without componentsSeparatedByString method..

Comment: Sounds like an homework, maybe you should try to put some efforts in it before asking in SO...

Comment: If all else fails, write code to step through the string a character at a time, recognize word breaks, and reassemble the way you want.  Yes, there are other tricks you can use, but probably no more efficient.

Answer (score 6):

You can enumerate strings by words.

```
NSString *string = @"Welcome to Objective-C!";

NSMutableArray *words = [NSMutableArray array];

[string enumerateLinguisticTagsInRange:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])
                                scheme:NSLinguisticTagSchemeTokenType
                               options:0
                           orthography:nil
                            usingBlock:^(NSString *tag, NSRange tokenRange, NSRange sentenceRange, BOOL *stop) {
                                [array addObject:[string substringWithRange:tokenRange]];
                            }];

NSMutableString *reverseString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

for (NSString *word in [words reverseObjectEnumerator]){
    [reverse appendString:word];
}

NSLog(@"%@", reverseString);
```

This will print...

```
"!C-Objective to Welcome"
```

You can change the options to omit whitespaces and stuff...

Comment: You're welcome. This function is actually very powerful. You can find types of words, word origins, verbs, nouns, adjectives, etc... using this function. Also a very fast way of editing attributed strings to add highlighting etc...

Comment: Can we do it in some more simple way..?

Comment: Not really. There are other ways where you can parse through character by character to work out where words begin and end and then store them in an array. But essentially you're doing exactly what this function does. This is by far the easiest and quickest way of doing what you want without using componentSeparatedByString.

Comment: actually an interviewer asked me to print a reverse of NSString "Welcome to Objective-C!" to "C-Objective to Welcome" without use of componentSeparatedByString method..but i did it by componentSeparatedByString method

Comment: Isn't that really just a generalized form of componentsSeparatedByString?

Comment: No, it's an entirely different function. componentsSeparatedByString will break in certain languages. Japanese, for instance, doesn't use white spaces a word separators so componentSeparatedByString:@" " wouldn't work. Essentially though, yes you are doing the same thing. But then so is any function that you use to reverse the word order of a string. Also, cSBS won't see punctuation, ie. Objetcive-C would still be Objective-C not C-Objective.

Comment: Ah! I was trying to do that originally but didn't know the reverseObjectEnumerator! Will definitely be using that in the future. Thanks :D

Comment: That's why I like this site, you give; you get back :)

Answer (score 2):

I used below method for reversing string in iOS

```
- (NSString *)reverseString:(NSString *)stringToReverse
{
    NSMutableString *reversedString = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:[stringToReverse length]];
    [stringToReverse enumerateSubstringsInRange:NSMakeRange(0, [stringToReverse length])
                                        options:(NSStringEnumerationReverse | NSStringEnumerationByComposedCharacterSequences)
                                     usingBlock:^(NSString *substring, NSRange substringRange, NSRange enclosingRange, BOOL *stop) {
            [reversedString appendString:substring];
    }];
    return reversedString;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I misread your question earlier. I did it using a series of loops, my answer is messier than Fogmeister but I wanted to give it a shot to see if I could do it.

```
NSString *str = @"This is a test";


    NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for(int i = 0; i < [str length]; i++)
    {
        char sTest = [str characterAtIndex:i];
        if(sTest == ' ')
        {
            [array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]];
        }
    }

    NSInteger iNext = [[array objectAtIndex:[array count]-1] integerValue];
    iNext+=1;

    if(iNext < [str length])
    {
       [array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:iNext]]; 
    }

    NSMutableArray *wordArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for(int i = 0; i < [array count]; i++)
    {
        if (i == 0)
        {
            int num = [[array objectAtIndex:i] integerValue];
            NSString *s = [[str substringFromIndex:0] substringToIndex:num];
            [wordArray addObject:s];

        }
        else if(i == [array count]-1)
        {
            int prev = [[array objectAtIndex:i-1] integerValue]+1;
            int num =  [str length];
            NSString *s = [[str substringToIndex:num] substringFromIndex:prev];
            [wordArray addObject:s];
        }
        else
        {
            int prev = [[array objectAtIndex:i-1] integerValue]+1;
            int num = [[array objectAtIndex:i] integerValue];

            NSString *s = [[str substringToIndex:num] substringFromIndex:prev];
            [wordArray addObject:s];
        }
    }

    NSMutableArray *reverseArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for(int i = [wordArray count]-1; i >= 0; i--)
    {

        [reverseArray addObject:[wordArray objectAtIndex:i]];
    }
    NSLog(@"%@", reverseArray);
```

Comment: Good Concept..great thought

Answer (score 1):

Here i have done with replacing character with minimal number of looping. log(n/2).

```
NSString  *string=@"Happy World";
NSInteger lenth=[string length];
NSInteger halfLength=[string length]/2;

for(int i=0;i<halfLength;i++)
{
   NSString *leftString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",[string characterAtIndex:i]];
   NSString *rightString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",[string characterAtIndex:(lenth-i-1)]];

   string= [string stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(i, 1) withString:rightString];
   string=[string stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange((lenth-i-1), 1) withString:leftString];

}

NSLog(@"%@",string);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This , It's working perfect as per your expectation ,

Call Function :-

```
 [self reversedString:@"iOS"];
```

Revers String Function :-

```
 -(void)reversedString :(NSString *)reversStr

 {    // reversStr is "iOS"

     NSMutableString *reversedString = [NSMutableString string];
     NSInteger charIndex = [reversStr length];
     while (charIndex > 0) {
     charIndex--;
     NSRange subStrRange = NSMakeRange(charIndex, 1);
    [reversedString appendString:[reversStr substringWithRange:subStrRange]];
  }
   NSLog(@"%@", reversedString); // outputs "SOi"
 }
```

Hope So this is help for some one .

Answer (score 0):

There is no API to do that, if that's what you are asking.

You can always iterate through the string looking for white spaces (or punctuation, it depends on your needs), identify the words and recompose your "reversed" message manually.

Comment: There is a built in method on NSString to enumerate by tags. See my answer.

Comment: Nice workaround :) actually what I meant is "there is no api that automagically reverse the order of the words in a string"

Comment: Ah, I see :D I love that function :D So useful for doing natural language parsing.